# C/C++ struct question

Tags: c++, c, struct

Suppose you have a .cpp file (that is, compiled using a C++ compiler like MSVC). In that file, you define a `struct` in the following way:

```
struct Pixel
{
   float x, y;
};
```

In the same file, you have a line of code that will call a C function, that requires a C `struct` equal to `Pixel`. If you write:

```
Pixel my_pixel
// set my_pixel to something
c_func(&my_pixel);
```

will it work? I mean, the C++ compiler will create the object `my_pixel`, but it will pass it to a function that is compiled as C code (i have only a .lib of that library).

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.8

Comment: The very next FAQ after the one to which Jonathan linked directly answers the OP's question. The answer to "Will it work?" is "Sometimes". In this case the answer should be "Yes" given that `struct Pixel` is a POD class.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the header file is correct, it will work, assuming the C compiler and the C++ compiler use compatible calling conventions. Make sure the header file has an appropriate `extern "C"` block that contains the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

The reason David Schzwartz says you need an `extern "C"` block is that without the extern "C" block, the compiler will "mangle" the name of the C function you are calling at the point you call it.  If you are calling a C function and not a C++ function, the function's definition in your library will not have a mangled name, so your executable will fail to link.

That's what you want if the function you are calling is written in C++, as name mangling allows for function name overloading. The types of each of a function's parameters are compactly encoded in the mangled function name.

Name mangling was originally provided in C++ to allow C++ object files to be linked with legacy linkers, rather than having to provide a C++-specialized linker that has explicit support for overloaded functions.

C doesn't permit function name overloading, so C function names are never mangled.  To provide a prototype in C++ for a single C function you do this:

```
extern "C" Foo( int theInt );
```

If you have a whole header file full of C function prototypes and you want to #include that header from a C++ source, enclose the #include in an extern C block

```
extern "C" {
    #include "Foo.h"
}
```